# Registration form not inserting new user

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple registration form.  I cannot figure out why it doesn't take the info submitted from the form and create the user in my database.  My database.php is pointing to the correct places so I am not sure what is up.

```
<?php
require_once('../template.php');
require_once('../database.php');
$page = new template(true, 'ForumSite');
$page->title = "Registration";
ob_start();
$errors = 1;
if(isset($_POST["register-submit"])){
    $alert = "success";
    $result = "Saved Profile";
    $errors = 0;
    extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "post");

    $conn = $db->NewConnection();
    $sql = "select * from users where username = '" . $username . "'";
    $user = $db->getArray($sql);
    if(!empty($user)){
        $alert = "danger";
        $result = "Error: user already exists";
        $errors++;
    } else{
        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $sql = "insert into users (username, password, email, date_registered, roleuser) values 
        (?,?,?,curdate(),2)";
            if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $hashedPassword, $email);
            $r = $stmt->execute() ? $stmt->get_result() : false;
            $stmt->close();
        }else {
            $errors++;
            $alert = "danger";
            $result = "Error: There was an error saving the User Account . " . $cn->errno . ": " .       
            $cn->error . "\n";
        }
$db->CloseConnection();
    }
?>
<div class="alert alert-<?= $alert ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong><?= $result ?></strong>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<?php
    if($errors == 0) {
?><div class="alert alert-<?= $alert ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong><?= $result ?></strong>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<?php
    if($errors == 0) {
?>
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $iduser;
    $_SESSION['UserDisplayName'] = $username;
    header('location: forumhome.php');
    }
}

if($errors > 0) {

?>

            <div class="col" id="registerbox">
                <div class="registerfield">
                    <h4 class="registerhead">Register</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="required_bar">
                    <h4 class="requiredbg">Required Information</h4>
                </div>
                <form class="registerform" method="post">
                    <label for="username">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="unsername" name="username"><br/>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  required><br/>
                    <label for="password2">Verify Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" required><br/>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br/>
                
                <br/>
                <div class="required_bar" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                    <h4 class="requiredbg">Verification</h4>
                </div>
                <div id="regsubmit">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark regbut" name="register-submit" 
                     value="Register">
                </div>
                </form>
<?php
}
$result=ob_get_clean();
$page->content=$result;
$page->Display();
```

I just end up with my error statement saying something went wrong.  I have tried also binding the  date_registered and the roleuser, which also gets me the same result.  I am stuck and not sure what else I am missing.

Comment: You never set the variables `$username`, `$password`, or `$email`.

Comment: $username, $password and $email are not defined. You need to get the from the POST variables first.

Comment: P.S. Your `select *` statement is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. This query should be parameterised just like the "insert" query is.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.